# is there a way to save this PDF programmatically?

Tags: html, delphi, web-scraping, delphi-10.1-berlin

Using Delphi 10.1, I have a PDF loaded in a `TWebBrowser` component. Is there a way to save the PDF programatically, which is displayed in my PDF plugin?

The URL of the PDF (embedded in the site) is: [MSDS-File for Productnr G7126 from Sigma-Aldrich](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=AT&language=de&productNumber=G7126&brand=SIGMA&PageToGoToURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sigmaaldrich.com%2Fcatalog%2Fsearch%3Fterm%3DG7126%26interface%3DAll_DE%26N%3D0%26mode%3Dmatch%2520partialmax%26lang%3Dde%26region%3DAT%26focus%3Dproduct)

Answer (score 2):

i don't think that it is possible by web-scraping (as you seem to want), i created this code that is suppose to find all iframes and download it but the urls look really wierd (and it generates an error because of it)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = "https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=FR&language=de&productNumber=G7126&brand=SIGMA&PageToGoToURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sigmaaldrich.com%2Fcatalog%2Fsearch%3Fterm%3DG7126%26interface%3DAll_DE%26N%3D0%26mode%3Dmatch%2520partialmax%26lang%3Dde%26region%3DAT%26focus%3Dproduct";
r = requests.get(url)

if r.status_code == 200:
    s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    for e in s.find_all('iframe'):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(e['src'], 'file.pdf')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your ideas. I learned from that (possible) solution.

Comment: which language do you use here?

Comment: I could get the iframe after the page is processed by javascript. But how can I get now the PDF via `TWebBrowser` My new Question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66583660/delph-10-1-how-to-load-a-pdf-file-from-an-url-via-twebbroswer

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair that is python