# How to load a PDF file from an URL via TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, pdf, delphi-10.1-berlin, twebbrowser

I have a extracted an URL from an iframe in an HTML page online with `TWebBrowser` and this URL retrieves a PDF file. How can I save this reply in a File locally by using `TWebBrowser`?

The line in the String `content4 := WebBrowser4.OleObject.Document.documentElement.innerHTML;`
looks like this:

```
                <iframe name="msdsPageFrame" width="1000" height="1200" id="msdsPageFrame" src="/MSDS/MSDS/PrintMSDSAction.do?name=msdspdf_210370071046219" style="z-index: 1;"></iframe>
```

Here is a demo source in Delphi 10.1 with `TWebBrowser` [ZIP-Standard_Delphi_10.1](https://mediencenter.t-mobile.at/lnk/TiDPy3Ts)

Comment: I suggest you first try to extract the path from the innerHTML (simple string handling, easy with Delphi), prefix that path with the site URL and use TWebBrowser Navigate2 function to download the URL.

Comment: @fpiette thanks as the page with provides the PDF is a Javascript page. On load the js is executed and the PDF is loaded. I have added a demo code.

Comment: You sample code is not standalone, I can't compile it. Please remove every dependency that is not included with Delphi.

Comment: @fpiette sorry and thanks for the info. I delete the two Telhttpsclient and Cookiemanger componets and reuploaded it